# Сторонние библиотеки InteliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Для задания понадобилась [библиотека](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/). Нужна помощь с ее установкой. Куда необходимо распаковать файлы и как импортировать библиотеку в ide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скачать Binaries отсюда http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi, распаковать в какую-либо директорию

Потом нажать `File` → `ProjectStructure` → `ProjectSettings/Libraries` → `Add` и выбрать папку или нужный jar:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно сработать

---

Если через `Maven`, то проще. В POM.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Добавил dependency, дальше idea все сделала за меня.

Comment: @PavelBobrov да, с maven всё проще)

Answer (score 1):

File - Project Structure - далее см. скриншот

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]